# Syntax for specifying relative paths in a Vagrantfile on Windows?

Tags: ruby, relative-path, vagrantfile

What is the syntax for specifying paths in a `Vagrantfile` on Windows?  I want to do something like the following:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "$VagrantProjectHome/src/000-default.conf", destination: "/etc/apache2/000-default.conf"
...
end
```

I'm pretty sure the syntax is ruby, and thus the `File.join` operator should be in there somewhere; but I don't know how to specify a relative path to my project directory on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source: `src/000-default.conf` did the trick.  It doesn't have any fancy syntax for Windows like most programs on Windows.

However, I couldn't actually copy files into any folders other than `/tmp` because of permission errors related to the use of SCP.  After they are copied over with SCP to `/tmp`, you can use `mv` in a `shell` provisioner to move it anywhere on the system.